# Call to undefined function fastcgi_finish_request()

Tags: php, linux, windows

Tenho um servidor Linux onde o php está configurado com nginx + fcgi.

A função [fastcgi_finish_request](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php) funciona corretamente como esperado.

Tenho uma outra máquina com Windows 10, configurada com apache + fcgi.
O arquivo httpd.conf do windows tem o seguinte trecho de configuração:

```
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so

FcgidInitialEnv PATH "c:/php;C:/WINDOWS/system32;C:/WINDOWS;C:/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem;"
FcgidInitialEnv SystemRoot "C:/Windows"
FcgidInitialEnv SystemDrive "C:"
FcgidInitialEnv TEMP "C:/WINDOWS/Temp"
FcgidInitialEnv TMP "C:/WINDOWS/Temp"
FcgidInitialEnv windir "C:/WINDOWS"
FcgidIOTimeout 64
FcgidConnectTimeout 16
FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 1000 
FcgidMaxProcesses 50 
FcgidMaxRequestLen 8131072
# Location php.ini:
FcgidInitialEnv PHPRC "c:/php"
FcgidInitialEnv PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS 1000

<Files ~ "\.php$>"
  AddHandler fcgid-script .php
  FcgidWrapper c:/php/php-cgi.exe .php
</Files>
```

Em ambas as máquinas todos os scripts php funcionam corretamente, com exceção desta função.
No Windows recebo um erro fatal informando que a função não existe.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function fastcgi_finish_request() in C:\www\teste.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\www\teste.php on line 5
```

- A função fastcgi_finish_request existe no Windows?
- Preciso habilitar algo adicional no php.ini?

O trecho inicial do meu phpinfo() no Windows 10:

```
PHP Version 7.1.0
System  Windows NT NB67000 10.0 build 10586 (Windows 10) AMD64
Build Date  Dec 2 2016 05:20:58
Compiler    MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015)
Architecture    x64
Configure Command   cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--enable-debug-pack" "--with-pdo-oci=c:\php-sdk\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-12c=c:\php-sdk\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--without-analyzer" "--with-pgo"
Server API  CGI/FastCGI
Virtual Directory Support   enabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   C:/Windows
Loaded Configuration File   C:\php\php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files     (none)
Additional .ini files parsed    (none)
PHP API     20160303
PHP Extension   20160303
Zend Extension  320160303
Zend Extension Build    API320160303,TS,VC14
PHP Extension Build     API20160303,TS,VC14
Debug Build     no
```

Comment: Olá, veja se ajuda: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23595092/fastcgi-finish-request-undefined

Comment: @FernandoMertins, já havia visto essa pergunta. Infelizmente o usuário que respondeu não mencionou qual era a configuração que estava incorreta.

Comment: Envia por favor o início da saída da phpinfo() no PC Windows10?

Comment: @FernandoMertins , editei a pergunta. Veja se isto já o suficiente ou se precisa de mais. Se possível, indique qual trecho lhe é interessante para análise.

Comment: Erro fatal seria `undefined`?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, sim, funções indefinidas ao serem chamadas provocam um erro fatal na engine do php.

Comment: Eu sei, é que as vezes a mensagem fala mais coisas importante, por isto sempre coloque o erro todo, sempre esculto alguém me falar algo do genero, mas muitas vezes as mensagens tem algo a mais que indica algo. Resumindo era somente para confirmar.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, adicionei a mensagem de erro para não deixar dúvidas.

Comment: Teu PHP é TS ou NTS?

Comment: Como você pode observar no phpinfo(), ele é Thread Safe.

Comment: Pelo que estou pesquisando, esta função só vai existir se o Server API estiver como *FPM/FastCGI* Encontrei http://stackoverflow.com/a/12983778/1694568

Comment: Mais uma para ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539670/php-fpm-for-windows

Comment: @jlHertel tenho quase certeza que TS é usado em apache2handler e NTS em Fast-cgi, tente NTS. Todavia acho que o problema é que você baixou uma versão binária e instalou, ou seja esta função não é disponivel no php-Fastcgi por padrão. A doc está um pouco vaga, vou testar quando chegar em casa

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, testei instalando o NTS, e o erro permanece.